# Anyone know what this symbol is - an 8 on its side with a vertical line through it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize

Anyone know what this symbol is - an 8 on its side with a vertical line through it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## ⧞

Infinity negated with vertical bar U+29DE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The infinity symbol is also known as the lemniscate.

[image]

https://www.geogebra.org/m/yha2pryd